# groovy: get a value(which is a list) from the key in map

Tags: groovy

I have been trying to get a particular value(which is a list) from a key in a map. I always get a `[null, null]`. I have tried everything from the stuff I found online.

```
// returns null

def key = "name"
def map = [name:[hello, there]]
log.debug "map value ${map[key]}"

// returns hello

def key = "name"
def map = [name:"hello"]
log.debug "map value ${map[key]}"
```

How do I get the above to return the value as a list i.e. `[hello, there]`?

Comment: `hello` and `there` are probably initialized to null. Where are these variables defined and initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the map with strings (rather than without quotes as you have it in your question) like so:

```
def key = "name"
def map = [name:['hello', 'there']]
```

Then `map[key]` will return the list `['hello', 'there']`

```
assert map[key] == ['hello', 'there']
```

Comment: That works! such a noob mistake. How can I convert those values into strings while creating the map itself? @tim_yates

Comment: No idea, you don't explain enough about your situation in your question. If you have `def hello = 'hello'` and the same for `world`, then your code should work

Comment: I am creating the map at a separate place. The code to create the map is as below -     `map = [names, surnames].collect {
  [(it): it.numbers]
 }`. The numbers over here are not strings. If I find a way to save them as strings, the above solution will work for me. @tim_yates

Comment: i tried `it.numbers.collect { it.toString()}`, but that isn't working either.

Comment: Can you put your actual question in the question? It feels like you simplified the problem to a point where it isn't your problem any more, and I can't see from the comments what it is you're doing

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes around your string values. Instead of

```
def key = "name"
def map = [name:[hello, there]]
log.debug "map value ${map[key]}"
```

You need

```
def key = "name"
def map = [name:['hello', 'there']]
log.debug "map value ${map[key]}"
```